# Issue while using UI Automator Viewer

Tags: android, android-uiautomator

This is the [screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VkM3V.png) in android app which I need to identify the elements with UI Automator Viewer, but while trying to get the screenshot with UI Automator, I am getting error as :

```
Error while obtaining UI hierarchy XML file: com.android.ddmlib.ShellCommandUnresponsiveException
Error while obtaining UI hierarchy XML file: com.android.ddmlib.ShellCommandUnresponsiveException
```